# What's the name of this design pattern (if it is one)?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I have a class that acts purely as a data store for other class instances.  Something like:

```
class Mover
{
      Position position;
      Velocity linearVelocity;
      Velocity angularVelocity;
 }
```

The Half-Life (Quake too?) engine did this sort of thing with its `pev` pointer, grouping a bunch of data into one container object.

Is this called something?  I want to do some reading on best practices and proper naming conventions.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no design patter evident here. At most, just some standard, neat naming convention.

Comment: @RobinMaben, I believe that is the answer to the question

Comment: To me it is just [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) of data

Comment: @Habib: Then I better put it down as one. :)

Comment: I don't see any functionality (methods) here, this is just a POJO, a plain struct, or whatever you call it in your language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific design pattern under consideration here.

Although the object under consideration is called a [**Value Object**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject)

Also refer to this : [**Can Value Objects Contain Reference Objects**](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CanValueObjectsContainReferenceObjects)

Answer (score 3):

There's no design pattern evident here. At most, just some standard, neat naming convention.

Encapsulation is not a design pattern by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of objects ("grouping a bunch of data into one container object") resembles [Object Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

The naming convention resembles [Self Documenting Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

Comment: @RobinMaben yes, imo. but that's really subjective. within the domain of self-documenting code, "too descriptive" can be too wordy/noisy for some people, and some self documenting code can also be too short or over-abbreviated. preferred amount of detail also varies by the reader's understanding of the implementation's subject. but yes, good code should be self documenting... and build without warnings too :)

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I totally agree on the "reader's understanding" part. :)